# Thinktecture v3 auto login for ADFS users within the same domain

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, thinktecture-ident-server

I am using Thinktecture identity server v3 for authentication and authorization. It works good with local database. I added external identity provider as ADFS. It also works good but it asks credentials for intranet users. My requirement is automatically login the intranet users without asking credentials. If the user is internet user, it asks for credentials. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unrelated to IdentityServer3. Your browser and ADFS need to be configured correctly to use Windows integrated authentication.

Comment: How can we logout from ADFS after logout in IdentityServer3?